# Budgie Question: is there a way to display the date with the time?

Tags: display, time, date, budgie

In almost every ubuntu flavor you can display the date next to the time, but some far I have not been able to find this option.  I could click on the calendar and view the date, but it just bugs me that I can't just look at it.  I feel like it is something on every device I have or have had.

I imagine when I right-click the time, there should be a checkbox where I can add/remove the date from that.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do a bit of terminal work for this.  Don't worry - its not complicated.

Open your terminal and copy - paste the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date true
```

This will display the date in the format of your region-locale.

To hide the date:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date false
```

Answer (score 4):

Budgie 10.3 provides option to customize time shown on budgie panel. With this update, you can enable date with a single click.

[image]

---

Currently, Ubuntu Budgie/budgie-remix provides budgie 10.2.9. Though in near future it will ship budgie 10.3 and can be installed from *ubuntu budgie backport* repository.

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntubudgie/+archive/ubuntu/backports